# VBA code for Excel application input box

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the below VBA code to match and delete some data in Excel,
I would like to use the application input box to input the required column name and replace the "B" in my code by this entry data

```
Sub ahmed_code()
Dim lr As Long, r As Long, x As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
lr = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For r = lr To 2 Step -1
x = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("Sheet2!$A:$A"), Cells(r, "B"))
If x = 0 Then
  Cells(r, "B").Resize(, 500).Delete Shift:=xlUp
End If
Next r
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "DONE YA M3alem ... Ahmed.Sousi ^_^ "
End Sub
```

Comment: What happened when you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Using code like:

```
Sub PickColumn()
   Dim r As Range, MyCol As String
   Set r = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="click a cell in the column", Type:=8)
   MyCol = Split(r.Address, "$")(1)
   MsgBox MyCol
End Sub
```

and in your code replace *"B"* with `MyCol`